# Local notifications working on ios simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, unusernotificationcenter

I've been working on getting local notifications working on this app I'm working on. I've setup the notification content with some text in the title, body etch and then setup the UNCalendarNotificationTrigger

```
NSDate *tenSecondsFromNow = [cal dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitSecond value:10 toDate:[NSDate date] options:NSCalendarMatchFirst]
UNCalendarNotificationTrigger* trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger
                                          triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:[cal components:NSCalendarUnitYear |
                                                                             NSCalendarUnitMonth|
                                                                             NSCalendarUnitDay|
                                                                             NSCalendarUnitWeekday |
                                                                             NSCalendarUnitHour|
                                                                             NSCalendarUnitMinute|
                                                                                   NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:tenSecondsFromNow] repeats:NO];
```

and I schedule the notification to run 10 seconds after I run this

```
    // Schedule the notification.
[_notificationCentre addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        DDLogError(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
        DDLogError(@"%@", @"couldn't create chore reminder notification");
    }
}];
```

What I'm struggling with is that when I run this code on the simulator, the notification does exactly what I would expect, shows me a notification 10 seconds after I run this piece of code when in the foreground or the background. However when I run this on my device, the notification doesn't appear. However when I change the trigger to be a UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger setup here

```
UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval:10 repeats:NO];
```

Which is essentially doing the same thing, scheduling a notification 10 seconds after the `addNotificationRequest` function is called. This works on both the simulator and my device.

I'm wondering if there is some weird time stuff going on? or maybe the simulator handles notifications slightly differently than the device. Either way, I've got no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why this works, but reducing the number of date components to match in the trigger "fixed it". I still don't know the root cause of the problem, but changing the data component part to

```
[cal components:NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:tenSecondsFromNow]
```

Fixed the problem.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, you should accept the answer.

Comment: I can only accept my own answer in 9 hours, I plan on doing that when I am able to.